# Is it approriate to create separate Azure Key Vaults in different Azure Environments?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm about to create three different environments within my Azure Subscription. `Dev`, `Test` and `Prod`.

However, I am unsure whether it is common practice to use one Key Vault that contain secrets from all three environments or should I create three separate Key Vaults, one for each RG?
What is "Best Practice" when it comes to this?

Comment: This will probably be of help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/best-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended choice is to use a vault per application per environment (development, pre-production, and production), per region. This helps you not share secrets across environments and regions. It will also reduce the threat in case of a breach.